# Retriving mapped table via ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to put some of the values of a table from the database to a `HashMap`. Here is what I do with the resultSet. I have in my database the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE myguests (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
)
```

and a mapping class for it :

```
 @Entity
 @Table
 public class MyGuests {
  @Column
  @Id
  public Integer id;
  @Column
  public String firstname;
}
```

Here is how I extract the table:

```
String basicQuery = "SELECT * FROM myguests";
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(basicQuery);

while (resultSet.next()) {
    Map<Field, Object> mapInfo = new HashMap<>();
    Field[] declaredFields = MyGuests.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < declaredFields.length; i++) {
        mapInfo.put(declaredFields[i],
            resultSet.getString(declaredFields[i].getName().toString().toLowerCase()));
    }
}
```

However I get error on the line:

```
mapInfo.put(declaredFields[i],
    resultSet.getString(declaredFields[i].getName().toString().toLowerCase()));
```

With the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.
```

I can't understand why the result set cannot fetch, I am looking in the database it is clearly filled and has columns named id, firstname

Comment: When you debug the value of `resultSet` what is contained in it?

Comment: @lealceldeiro I can see some of its'properties: fetchSize=0,thisrow=null etc. which one are you interested it to tell it's value

Comment: the thing is... in `resultset` are comming rows which do not contain the `id` field (as the error says), put a breakpoint in the `resultSet.getString ...` line and see what's in that rown in the moment it evaluates `declaredFields[i].getName()` and check what's happening there